# How can I increase my height?

Tags: diet, height, growth-hormones

I am 19 years old, around 1.62 meters tall and a weight of 55 kilograms, and I want to increase my height.

Is it possible to do it at my age? If so, can I have a specific diet or use growth hormones?

Comment: Use stilts. They work well

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in any means.

The growth of a child or a teenager is mainly due to the epiphyseal or [growth plates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyseal_plate) in the long bones of the body. The most important long bones are tibia, femur and humerus. Throughout the growing years of a human, cells divide constantly in the epiphyseal plates thus making the bones longer. Around the [age 17 (little earlier in girls)](http://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/pediatrics/growth-and-development/physical-growth-and-sexual-maturation-of-adolescents) the growth stops. The hallmark of this biological phenomenon is the [ossification of the growth plates](http://courses.washington.edu/conj/bess/growth/growth.html) and the cell division has ended.

As so in your age, there are no biological "sources" on growth which could be boosted in ways.

Comment: I am male. Also, I read somewhere that growth in males stops around 20 years old. Is that true?